# How to reset the values in database at specific interval of time?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am using **PHP Codeigniter**. For a system i want to allow **Reseller** to add balance to his own users. The condition is that he can allot only **5 EUROS** to each of his user,not less and not more then 5. Suppose **Reseller** current balance is 20 EUROS then he should be able to allot only 5 EUROS, So 4 users each will get 5 euros each, and the most important i want to reset tha balance of user to zero after every **30 days**, i mean on end of one month. The reseller balance should deduct as per his division among the users while the users balance would be set to zero every 30 days. I am really confused from where to start and how!

the Controller Code:

```
public function edit ($id = NULL)
            {

                  $usertype=$this->session->userdata('usertype');
                  if($usertype ==="admin")
                    {

                        // Fetch a user or set a new one
                        if ($id) {
                        $this->data['user'] = $this->reseller_m->get($id);
                        count($this->data['user']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'User could not be found';
                    }
                  else 
                  {
                        $this->data['user'] = $this->reseller_m->get_new();
                  }

                        // Set up the form
                        $rules = $this->reseller_m->rules_admin;
                        $id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
                        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

                        // Process the form
                        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

        $data = $this->reseller_m->array_from_post(array('sip_username','sip_password','key','allocation_block','name','email','password','phone','balance','user_num','address','country','country_code','created','modified','status'));


                    $data['password'] = $this->reseller_m->hash($data['password']);

                    $key=$this->reseller_m->save($data, $id);

                //here we get the last inserted record id in $last_id// 
                    $last_id = $this->db->insert_id();

                //The logic to create key to uniquely identify a reseller.

                    $values=array($this->input->post('name'),$this->input->post('country_code'),$this->input->post('allocation_block'),$this->input->post('user_num'));

                    $key=implode('-',$values);

                    $this->db->where('id',$last_id);
                    $this->db->update('reseller',array('key'=>$key));

                    //Loop To Creates Users Dynamically as user_num value.

                    $this->reseller_m->get($id);


                    if($id === NULl)
                    {
                        for($i=1; $i<=$data['user_num'];$i++)
                        {

                        $userdata=array('key'=>$key);

                        $this->db->insert('users',$userdata);

                        }
                    }

                    redirect('admin/reseller');
                }

                // Load the view
                $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/reseller/edit';
                $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
            }
            else
            {

                $this->load->view('permission');
            }


            }
```

Comment: Please add your code to be reviewed

Comment: @Michelem i have added the admin controller code. should i post the reseller controller code as well?

Comment: @Michelem my system flow is as follow: reseller provide information to admin. admin creates reseller. reseller has a filed no_users so the time reseller is created users are also created mapped to that reseller id. admin allots balance to reseller as requested. now reseller has to divide the balance among his users and he can only give 5 euros to any user which will be reset to zero after 30 days

Comment: For resetting after 30 days you should use a `cronjob`.

Comment: does cron job allow me to reset the values in database? and is this safe?

Comment: hello how to create a cron job for this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Mysql Event Scheduler for this.

For more detail following link - 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Comment: actually m new to codeigniter i dont think i will be able to use this is CI.